# Not passing the value in the object within function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, object

The **listCount--** inside the **function removeItem** do not pass the value in list.itemCount but the **itemLists.splice(indexOfLi, 1);** in the same function is perfectly removing the value in the list.itemList. I am confused, what's the problem of this? Thanks.

```
const list = {
    itemCount: 0,
    itemList: []
  };

function displayValue(countText, itemLists, listCount, ulVar) {
  countText.append(` (${listCount})`);

  for (let i = 0; i < listCount; i++) {
    createElement(itemLists[i]?.item, itemLists[i]?.time, ulVar);
  }

  removeItem(itemLists, listCount, countText);
}


function removeItem(itemLists, listCount, countText) {
  const fontASTrash = $('.fa-trash');

  fontASTrash.off().on('click', function () {
    const indexOfLi = $(this).parent().parent().index();

    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    itemLists.splice(indexOfLi, 1);
    listCount--;
    countText.text(`Item List (${listCount})`);

  });
}


displayValue(itemListText, list.itemList, list.itemCount, ulItemList);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`listCount` variable inside the `removeItem` function does not contain a reference to the `list.itemCount` value and is actually a standalone variable.

The reason why this happens is because when the following is called:

`displayValue(itemListText, list.itemList, list.itemCount, ulItemList);`

The `.itemCount` value is passed in as standalone primitive values that are no longer part of the `list` object, so you can change it inside `displayValue` and `removeItem` functions but it will no longer augment the value inside the `list` object.

This behaviour can also be illustrated when destructuring objects as doing the following will no longer edit the value inside `list`:

```
const { itemCount } = list;
itemCount--; // this will no longer change list.itemCount
```

The fix would be to simply pass the object to the `displayValue` and `removeItem` functions. E.g:

```
displayValue(itemListText, list, ulItemList);
```

And use them with the object reference. e.g. `list.itemCount--`.

Comment: but how `itemLists.splice(indexOfLi, 1);` inside the removeItem function can manipulate the `list.itemList` ? I am confused because I thought that the parameters in the function are pointing at the same heap of the object.

Comment: ```itemCount``` is a primitive value - a number, so when you pass ```list.itemCount``` into a function, the function creates a new argument called ```listCount```  which is a unique variable within the heap of the function. This does not happen for objects, so when you pass ```list.itemList```, the function still keeps a reference to the list object that is attached to ```list``` and so the augmentations that happen inside the function edit the property inside list. My original response regarded ```itemList``` as a primitive variable, which was a mistake and I have made a fix for it.

Comment: This subject is commonly known as ```pass-by-value``` vs ```pass-by-reference``` where object structures do not lose their reference when passed inside function parameters, but primitive types do